# Webscraping my grades

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a program that grabs my school grades from a website everyday. Then stores the values and creates a graph for my grades, but when i try to scrape the page the HTML that i receive is different then the HTML that i get with inspect element.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("https://ames.usoe-dcs.org/Students/2567")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml');
print(bsObj)
```

inspect element gives me: http://pastebin.com/BakmpqUM

while python gives me: http://pastebin.com/7gPY1WgB

i figure this is because the URL to my grades (https://ames.usoe-dcs.org/Students/2567) is private, so when you type it into the browser it returns me here:https://ames.usoe-dcs.org/Login/?DestinationURL=%2FStudents%2F2566

is there a way to use python to automatically sign me in?

Comment: You'll have to figure out how the site is allowing you to be authenticated in the browser. For instance, when you login with your username/password successfully, the HTTP response likely comes back with a `Set-Cookie` header, which you'd have to pass along with all your subsequent HTTP requests.

Comment: If the site never logs you out, then you could just save the cookie with your script (instead of your username and password).

Answer (score 0):

The URL isn't necessarily private, however requesting the URL without cookies verifying your status as a user won't get you to the information you see when you logged in.

I would recommend opening Inspect Element to the network tab and reloading the page with your grades on it (while signed in). Then right click on the first request (should be a GET request answered with HTML, code 200), hover over copy, then click `Copy as cURL command (bash)`. Then paste into [this webpage](https://curl.trillworks.com/) and copy the python. It will give you the proper request for the page including the cookies and verification parameters you used to access them in the browser. From there you can parse the HTML response for your grade.

You should have something like this to receive and parse your HTML from the request:

```
cookies = {
   ...stuff...
}
headers = {
   ...stuff...
}

r = requests.get("https://ames.usoe-dcs.org/Students/2567", headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
grade = soup.find("h1", {"class":"grade"}).contents # Customize to find your grade
print(grade)
```

The cookies and headers dictionaries come from the cURL to Python output.

Comment: how do i get the HTML from the python request? i'm not familiar with requests

Comment: I worded the top comment weirdly, how do i get the value of my grades after using the website?

Comment: You'll have to learn some of the basics of BeautifulSoup. Basically the first argument is the tag name of the element that contains your grade, and after that you can create a dictionary of element attributes and values that specify which element you are referring to. The contents attribute at the end takes the inner HTML of the element.

Comment: i tried print(r) and i got <Response [404]> is this normal?

Comment: I feel bad for asking too many questions but i tried your code and i got                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gerald\Python\matplotlibTesting.py", line 26, in <module>
    soup = bs4(r.text, "lxml")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Ahhh, your BeautifulSoup import should be "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup". bs4 is the module, BeautifulSoup is the class you want. Then "soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")"